# Remove view from Telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

I have been trying to remove view from the template in telescope since I am only using Daily views and the only option is daily. However after trying pretty much everything I can't find a way to do it without crashing the site.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm curious to know what you tried that managed to crash the site? Also, did you check out the documentation beforehand?

Comment: I did check the documentation, but I'm learning meteor so I probably made some stupid mistakes (I don't even remember what I changed).

Comment: No worries, just curious to know how I can improve the docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`client/lib/config.js`

```
Telescope.modules.remove("top","posts_views_nav");
```

Comment: where should I put that? cause I tried putting it in main.js and it crashed the site

Comment: I put it in `client/lib/config.js` and it works like a charm.